# I am trying to pass parameters in cassandra query but I am getting error using python

Tags: python, database, cassandra, nosql

```
 user_input== "b":
       id = input("Enter id of  your book")  
            idnum=int(id)
            column_name = input("Enter column name")
            delete= "delete %(column)s from books where book_id=%(i_d)s"
            session.execute(delete,{'column':column_name,'i_d':id})
```

I am getting following error while executing this code

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:/workspace/library_mangement_application/main.py", line 40, in 
> delete_data()
> File "e:/workspace/library_mangement_application/main.py", line 35, in delete_data
> session.execute(delete,{'column':column_name,'i_d':id})
> File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 2618, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
> File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 4894, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
> cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:7 mismatched input 'book_info' expecting K_FROM (delete ['book_inf]...)">

Answer (score 0):

So Python string formatting isn't a good way to inject variables in CQL.  That being said, it's not impossible to do with the column name.  So you could do something like this instead:

```
deleteCQL= "delete %s from books where book_id=?" % column_name
```

Then create a prepared statement based on `deleteCQL`, and then bind `idnum` at query execution time.

```
pStatement = session.prepare(deleteCQL)
session.execute(pStatement,[idnum])
```

This approach also helps with escaping any odd characters or punctuation inside the bind variables.